# What is wrong with this sed expression?

Tags: sed

sed 's_((checksum|compressed)=\").*(\")_\1\2_' -i filename

I am using this command to replace the checksum and compressed filed with empty? But it didn't change anything?

for example, I want change this line " checksum="XXXXX" with checksum="", and also replace
compressed="XXXX" with compressed=""

What is wrong with my sed command?

Comment: Is unix expanding the `*` into filenames in the current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because sed uses a funny regex dialect by default: you have to escape capturing brackets.
If you want to use "normal" regex that you're familiar with, use the `-r` flag (if you're on unix, GNU sed) or the `-E` flag (Mac OS X BSD sed):

```
sed -r 's_((checksum|compressed)=\").*(\")_\1\3_' -i filename
```

Additionally, note that you have three sets of capturing brackets in your `sed`, and I think you want to change the `\1\2` to `\1\3`. (\1 contains `checksum="`, \2 contains `checksum`, and \3 contains `"`).

(For interest, here's how you would do it without the extended-regexp (-r/-E) flag, note that capturing brackets and the OR `|` are only considered in the regex sense if they are escaped:

```
sed 's_\(\(checksum\|compressed\)=\"\).*\(\"\)_\1\3_' -i filename
```

)

Comment: Some terminology: the "funny" regex dialect is called a basic regular expression (used in sed and grep). The "normal" regex is (probably) an extended regular expression (used in awk and grep -E). Both BREs and EREs are found with extensions, notably in the GNU implementations. There are also Perl-style regular expressions (many variations, many languages).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo 'checksum="XXXXX" compressed="YYYYYYY"' | 
sed 's/\(checksum\|compressed\)="[^"]*"/\1=""/g'
checksum="" compressed=""
```

In sed (without the `-r` switch), `()|+?{}`'s must have a `\` prepended to give them the qualities of grouping. alternation, one or more, zero or one and intervals. `.[]*` work as metacharacters either way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed 's/\(\(checksum\|compressed\)\)="[^"]*"/\1=""/' -i filename
```